# Design pattern for a sequence of related operations

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, software-design

I have a use case where I need to process a request as follows

1. Authenticate the Request
2. Authorize the Request
3. Validate the message (Reads the database for the existing record and validates it)
4. Perform some asynchronous operations
5. Update the records in the database and notify the customer

The problem is I need to read the same record we read in step 3 in step 4 
and step 5
Since this looked 
like a workflow I thought I can use the COR design pattern. 
However I do not want to read the database record again in step 4 and 5 and want to pass this from step 3 to step 4 and 5.

What is an elegant design pattern I can use for this workflow. 
Can you help me with giving some class/interface structure for this?

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: the record will not be update between step 3, 4 and 5 ?

Comment: That sounds and smells like a stream or transformation pipeline of some sort. Except that step 2 doesn't seem to produce the input for step 3.

Comment: No. It will update only in 5.

Comment: It's always good to design your application in *layers*: a controller layer to handle and authorize external requests which calls the service layer, a service layer which validates the data and calls the repository layer and a repository layer which interacts with the database.

Comment: @PaulBenn when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: What is the problem to pass the record data from 3 to 5?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question about design pattern: simply put your data in cache memory like   [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)